# Multiple Regression Interpretation

Tags: r, regression

I have 3 Variables: Grass Minimum, Minimum Temp. and RH.
Grass Min. is my dependent variable and I need to see how the other 2 variables affect it. The calculations are done in different areas.

Area 1: Grass vs Min

```
  Call:
lm(formula = Grass ~ Min)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-10.5775  -0.5576   0.0636   0.6097   2.3573 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -2.513311   0.024164  -104.0   <2e-16 ***
Min          1.014186   0.001618   626.8   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9356 on 10626 degrees of freedom
  (297 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.9737,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9737 
F-statistic: 3.929e+05 on 1 and 10626 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The way to interpret this to see the correlation is by looking at the R^2 and p-value right?

Grass vs RH:

```
> model<-lm(Grass~RH08)
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = Grass ~ RH08)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-16.1283  -4.5832  -0.3155   4.8717  14.9746 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 14.779244   0.242547   60.93   <2e-16 ***
RH08        -0.050708   0.003679  -13.78   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 5.713 on 10594 degrees of freedom
  (329 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.01762,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.01753 
F-statistic:   190 on 1 and 10594 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Here we can see that our R^2 is quite low, but p-value is quite significant which leads that it does affect the Grass Min?

And for Grass ~ Min + RH:

```
> model<-lm(Grass~Min+RH08)
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = Grass ~ Min + RH08)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-10.5820  -0.5576   0.0645   0.6083   2.3624 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -2.5448234  0.0485845 -52.379   <2e-16 ***
Min          1.0143442  0.0016367 619.752   <2e-16 ***
RH08         0.0004483  0.0006083   0.737    0.461    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9359 on 10593 degrees of freedom
  (329 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.9736,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9736 
F-statistic: 1.956e+05 on 2 and 10593 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

On the last comparison with both independent variables, we can see that our R^2 is high, but the p-value for RH is not significant. My question is, how do I result from this data on how RH and Min.T affects the Grass Min?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for the Min variable things are pretty clear right? Strongly positively correlated, good at predicting grass etc

My understanding is that you are sceptical because of what happens at RH08 between the second and the third model.

Let's take a step back.
If you look at the coefficients, in the second model, the RH08 is significantly non-zero with a negative correlation tendency whereas in the last model, it becomes  zero with a little bit of positive flavour in it. Furthermore, the 3rd model is pretty much identical to the first one.

So we see that the small percentage of variability that was explained by RH08 in the second model was decreased even more by adding Min. Probably Min and RH08 are (negatively) correlated with a very small R square and that is why after you add Min the RH08 becomes insignificant. You can easily validate that by looking at their correlation.

That being said, in my opinion, you always need to look at the nature of the variables to implement a model. Without this knowledge, what seems to be more plausible to me is that the nature of RH08 significance in the second model is because it is slightly correlated with min grass indicating a potential confounding factor (it can be Min or a different variable)